# Google Spreadsheet "Document Name" ImportXML XPath Query

Tags: xpath, google-apps-script, google-sheets, custom-function, google-sheets-formula

I want to write an ImportXML function in a Google Spreadsheet to return the document name of the same spreadsheet. For example, my spreadsheet is titled "Kimchi". I want' to return that name in cell "A1" to automate a series of functions within the spreadsheet based on the document name. I'm too lazy to type the value into the cell for each of the hundred or so spreadsheets I'll copy from the original template and rename.

I can't seem to nail a correct query structure.

This bit of XML looked promising, but I can't seem to get the query to pull it:

```
<span class="docs-title" id="docs-title" role="button"><div class="docs-title-inner" id="docs-title-inner">kimchi</div></span>
```

I've tried so far...

```
=ImportXML("SOME URL HERE", "//div[@class=’docs-title-inner’]/@content")
```

It returns...

```
Error: Imported Xml content can not be parsed.
```

I've tried all kinds of variations, some probably equally poorly formed. Following is some of the XML structure that looked juicy:

```
<html>
  <head>
     <title>kimchi - Google Sheets</title>
```

But this XPath query within the ImportXML function didn't work either

```
=ImportXML("SOME URL HERE", "/html/head/title")
```

It returned...

```
Error: Import Internal Error.
```

I'm stumpted.

[Here's the spreadsheet with variations.](https://docs.google.com/a/almaheights.org/spreadsheets/d/1pERypkiPmPtRSa3axuBi0Wz2iVlOSVdMkdAwongvzk0/edit#gid=0)

PS This ended up working after I shared the document with the world:

```
=ImportXml("THE URL", "//meta[@itemprop='name']/@content")
```

Comment: Well, I can't explain this, but one of the variations I had tried earlier suddenly started working in the spreadsheet. I merely typed it into a different cell and bingo. Here's the winner... importxml("THE URL", "//meta[@itemprop='name']/@content").

Comment: Think I know what unlocked it: I shared the document to the world so I could post the link in this post. It must have been a permissions thing. Now I have a new problem. How do I keep the document private and still make the query work?

Comment: @boywick, were you able to find a solution to this without sharing the file to anyone with the link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont have to do any of that.
Go to `tools`-> `script editor` -> `blank project`

replace the contents of the edit window with the code below:

```
function BookName() {
  return SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getName();
}
```

`Ctrl-S`, put `BookName` in the name box, click ok, wait for the yellow "saving" bar to dissapear. Close the tab with the code editor.

In your sheet you can now simply type `=BookName()` and the cell will display the workbook title.

Comment: Well, not to say that the XPath odyssey wasn't fun, but this is much more elegant and opens up many more possibilities. Thank you for introducing me to the scripting tool user3616725!

Comment: Hi @user3616725, can we also get the name of the spreadsheet through the link in a cell and not just the active one?